# How to register an upstart service?

Tags: 14.10, upstart

I wrote an `upstart` service following the [Ubuntu wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto) and created a `.conf` file in `/etc/init/`. There're no instructions on how to proceed to make the script available in `initctl list` and for `upstart` management commands, like `start` and `service`. The [official upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook) doesn't explain this matter.

The start fails with

```
$ start archiva
start: Unknown job: archiva
$ service archiva start
archiva: unrecognized service
```

Comment: What does `initctl check-config` say? And did you do `sudo start archiva`? A simple `start` will check for session jobs, not system jobs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably there are some errors in you conf file. To verify it use:

```
 init-checkconf archiva.conf
```

or

```
initctl check-config archiva
```

as described in upstart cookbook: [10.1.6.2   initctl check-config](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#initctl-check-config) and [10.1.7   init-checkconf](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#init-checkconf).

Upstart use [init](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/init.5.html) daemon that, according to man page:

> On startup, the Upstart init(8) daemon reads its job configuration
>   from files  in  the  /etc/init/ directory, and watches for future
>   changes to these files using inotify(7).

So, once you place your configuration file in `/etc/init`, your service is enabled and on the next reboot the init daemon will start it.

Answer (score 1):

Upstart uses inotify. If you drop a configuration file into `/etc/init/`, Upstart should detect and make the job available automatically. If you don't see it appear, there may be a problem in your new configuration. Try checking the logs for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a variable in the `/etc/init/scriptname.conf` file in the form of `NAME=value` like you'd do in an `initd` script causes upstart to give this rather nonsense feedback (telling that there's a syntax error is much more suitable than saying that the script doesn't exist). Removing the line causes the script to be recognized and startable randomly (see my suggested improvement as [bug 1446577 on launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1446577) for details).